# require is not defined in electron.js app

Tags: javascript, electron

I am having an issue when attempting to import a library using the `require` method. I get an error that goes `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I have got `nodeIntegration` set to `true` in the `main.js` file and I am trying to use a library (I get the same error for any library) by using:

```
window.socket = require('websocketio');
```

inside if `renderer.js`.

I have tried using the `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` method in a `preload.js` file and having the file referenced in `main.js` when I create the new window.

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
let mainWindow;

// Creates the main window
function createMainWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: isDev ? 1920 : 1280,
    height: 720,
    icon: './images/icon.ico',
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    }
});

// Opens the dev tools if in development mode
if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, './renderer/index.html')).then(r => console.log(r));
//mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1');
```

}

Comment: Make sure all necessary libraries are loaded in the header of you page.

Comment: @Mehrwarz How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no point in using a preload file if you enable `nodeIntegration`. It is recommended that you keep `nodeIntegration` disabled for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security). When all security features are enabled, you can't (and shouldn't) use `require` on the renderer process.

Then, renderers are [sandboxed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox) by default, which means that you can only `require` some specific modules in your preload (emphasis mine):

> In order to allow renderer processes to communicate with the main process, preload scripts attached to sandboxed renderers will still have a polyfilled subset of Node.js APIs available. A `require` function similar to Node's `require` module is exposed, **but can only import a subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules**: [...]

Sandboxing is a security feature, if you want to keep it, all Node libraries you want to use have to be required on the main process, and you should use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/fr/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate between your main and renderer processes. If you don't want sandboxing (**but keep in mind that it's a security feature**), you can disable `sandbox` in the `webPreferences` of your window:

```
webPreferences: {
  contextIsolation: true,
  nodeIntegration: false,
  sandbox: false,
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
}
```